# get row name and column name on condition

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
help<-data.frame(A=c(1,0.5,0.3,0.2), B=c(0.5,1,0.3,0.2), C=c(0.1,0.5,0.3,1))
```

I would like to create a nested loop to loop over every cell in the df and save the rowname and colname if a conditional is met
eg if the value is > 0.7 save rowname and colname.

Would a key/value hash type variable be appropriate here? (Sorry am still a beginner in R).

At the moment I have :

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(help)) {
      for (j in 1:ncol(help)){
        if (help[i,j] >0.7){

          save rowname and colname to a variable?
 }
    }
       }
```

Comment: Add your expected output to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You need `which()` from base R -

```
which(help > 0.7, arr.ind = T)

     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   2
[3,]   4   3
```

Comment: How do I put an 'or' statement in this? I tried which(help > 0.7 ||  < -0.7, arr.ind = T)

Comment: `which(help > 0.7 | help < -0.7, arr.ind = T)`

Comment: Sorry - is there a way of extracting these form the original df. I tried help[which(help > 0.7 | help < -0.7, arr.ind = T),] but this didn't seem to work

Comment: @zoe - `help[which(help > 0.7 | help < -0.7, arr.ind = TRUE)]` - note no comma. Searching here for `[r] matrix indexing` will turn up a lot of useful, similar questions.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, although this gives me a vector of all the values meeting the conditional??

Comment: @zoe - yep. It's really the only option as it's not going to fit in a data.frame structure once you start extracting individual cells.